# How to change date format in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I would like to change this date 2015-06-08T00:00:00+02:00 into something like this 08/06/2015. I tried using NSDateFormatter but I couldn't find proper format for this date

Comment: do you want us to debug code you did not even post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"` to convert your `NSString` to `NSDate`

Code:

```
NSString *myString = @"2015-06-08T00:00:00+02:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx";
NSDate * myDate = [formatter dateFromString:myString];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";
NSString *newString = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

See [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) to format DateTime

Answer (score 0):

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

print("date: \(formatter.stringFromDate(yourDate))")
```

Comment: Date that I have is NSString, isn't a NSDate object. So this means that I need one more NSDateFormatter which I can use to convert this 2015-06-08T00:00:00+02:00 to NSDate. But I don't know which format should I use for this date that I have

Comment: Is your date always formatted like this ? you can convert it into a `String` that could be formatted by `NSDateFormatter`. In your case, `2015-06-08 00:00:00`, remove the `T` and the `+` part. It's much simpler than trying to find the correct format for `NSDateFormatter`.